# Does $f(x)$ has inflection point at $c$ if $f(x)$ is diffrentiable at interval $I$ and $f'(x) > 0$ at $I$ except $c$?

Tags: calculus

Does $f(x)$ has inflection point at $c$ if $f(x)$ is differentiable at interval $I$ and $f'(x) > 0$ at $I$ except at $c$ (interval $I$ includes $c$)?

I think it is geometrically true, but I can't prove strictly.

Comment: Do you mean to imply that $f'(c)=0$? Also, what is your _definition_ of inflection point?

Comment: @Arthur No. Just $f'(x) > 0$ is not true at $c$. In other words, $f'(c) <= 0$. But I can't find a case of $f'(c)<0$ so I think $f'(c)=0$

Comment: @Arthur definition of inflection point is same as usual  definition. According to wikipedia,

In differential calculus, an inflection point, point of inflection, flex, or inflection (British English: inflexion) is a point on a continuous plane curve at which the curve changes from being concave (concave downward) to convex (concave upward), or vice versa.

Comment: @Surb: There is an inflexion point at $x=0$

Comment: @Surb Yes. $f(x)=x^3$ is an example. But how can I prove counterexample does not exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Darboux theorem $f'$ has IVP. If $f'(c) <0$ then any number between $f'(c)$ and $0$ will  not be attained by $f'$ contradicting IVP. Hence it follows that $f'(c)$ must be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. $f'(c)=0$ must hold, due to Darboux's theorem, which states that $f'(x)$ has the intermediate value property.